# How do I modify a model to return specific db fields?

Tags: php, mysql, yii

A Yii question:

**The Situation:**
I generated a model using Yii's gii code generator tool. The model returns all fields in a given table in a MySQL database.

**The Problem:**
I want to return only fields related to a specific logged-in user based on their user id (which I get from `Yii::app()->user->getId()`)

**The Question:**
How can I modify my model to do this?

**Code:**
(*The 'rules' section of my Model class*)

```
public function rules()
{
   return array(
   array('user_id, title, description', 'required'),
   array('user_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
   array('description', 'length', 'max'=>255),
   array('id, user_id, title', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),

   // Is the solution something like this?
   //array('user_id', 'compare', 'user_id'=>Yii::app()->user->getId());
  );
}
```

Comment: I have no clue about yii but it looks to me that a "where" condition that will keep only the desired record must be entered. So look around in yii how-where to apply the where condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to modify the model -- how are you doing your search? If you want to use Active Record, you can do something like:

```
User::model()->find(array('condition'=>'user_id='.Yii::app()->user->getId()));
```

if the user id is the primary key then:

```
User::model()->findByPk(Yii::app()->user->getId());
```

and if you did want to add the condition to your model, you probably want to use a [scope](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#named-scopes) to define a search condition, rules are for checking data when it's submitted for insert/update.

For scopes, put this function in your model:

```
public function scopes() {
    return array(
        'userid'=>array(
            'condition' => 't.user_id = ' . Yii::app()->user->getId(),
        ),
    );
}
```

then you can use something like this to fetch the data:

```
User::model()->userid()->find();
```

(In the above change "User" to the name of your model.)

I would strongly recommend you read the db [documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.overview) and work through some tutorials.

Comment: thank you very much for such a helpful answer. This is why stack overflow is great.